# I am fascinated by hardware boards and coding directly with the hardware. I want to start?

Tags: embedded

I am already a software developer, but daily business work is neither challenging not improving my skills.

I have no clue how this embedded things work, what are the setup needs to be done to even run hello world program.

So I am looking for very basic development board, which is support at C language.
not very complicated or high processing. As that would be over killing for a just beginner.
if I am able to understand how to handle a small device. I would learn other upper level board. As it is self paced and self teaching. I don't wanna jump over a complicated board as that happened to me once. I have having LPC 21xx board, well equipped. having good space to create program and run them. 
But I was knocked out in the round zero. could not figured out more then plugging into computer and turn it on.
So suggest me simple board it would be great if it support usb as my laptop does not have serial port. if if there is nothing no issue, I hope there will be something usb to serial. :)
Please help. I really wanna learn it.

Comment: You can get a USB serial port cable at almost any place that sells cabling.  Having one of those will help with many or most embedded device evaluation boards, since a serial port is often used as a console or even to program the device.

Answer (score 3):

The arduino is very user friendly but in part because they hid the stuff you are trying to learn.  You can still get down to the metal on an arduino though

The winarm guy has tons of example programs to get you started.

Sparkfun is the place to go in the US for most boards.  right now the sam7-h64 is on sale, atmel has a util for covering the loading of the board problem.  you can get an mbed there, now the maple is there, coridium armmite pro, and a plethera of arduino variations.  And the msp430 launchpad.  No matter what I recommend picking up one of the msp430 launchpad boards, only $4.30, very nice architecture, the usb cable (that comes with it?) is all you need.

Another TI product is the stellaris line of cortex-m3 based chips/eval boards.  The 811 is easy to brick, I would avoid it, comes with everything you need.  the boards are dripping with goodies, oled display, buttons, etc.

At some point you are going to need to get your feet wet with openocd.  Amontek makes the jtag-tiny which is a very nice arm jtag wiggler.  A number of the eval boards have ftdi chips on them which handle usb to serial and usb to jtag, googling will show tons of info on how to use openocd to connect to and load.

Another path is qemu.  a stellaris board/chip or few and other chip families are supported, so you can cover the learning to compile/build the program as well as program some peripherals without having to figure out the loading part.

The atmel avr butterfly is still available for $20.  Three wires shoved into a serial port connector and you can program the thing.  Has things on the board to learn to program, etc.

I recommend not limiting yourself to one processor family (avr, arm, msp430, etc) nor one chip vendor (lpc, atmel, ti, etc).  many of these boards can be had for under $50, some under $25 (look at the ez430 additional boards 3 for $10, the launchpad might be able to program them, otherwise the ez430 is $20).  (most of the arduino family wants an additional usb to serial plus power, which almost doubles the cost, also be careful to note 5V vs 3.3V boards, so you dont melt anything down, really good idea to get a few of the different ftdi usb to serial breakout boards from sparkfun anyway).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've heard of [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/)... it's a great beginning hardware platform, programmed with USB in C++. Boards are only $30 so it's pretty cheap too.

Answer (score 0):

stm32l-discovery 14$ for stm32(16kb ram + 128kb flash + 4kb eeprom) + stlink2 on board, you just need an usb-cable. Be sure to get l version, not vl, the l- has slower cpu but an lcd and some touch sensitive buttons. I was a normal c developer before, but found a job in an embedded market, where we use the same processor. In a month I never used any assembler and the experience was not much different than programming for pc except for you can't effectively use dynamical allocation. But that doesn't matter, since you control all the memory and timing and all the hardware for that matter. The iar kickstart tools are also great, especially the debugger - it is fast and you can even attach to the running process. The editor in the IAR IDE sucks big time though. It still doesn't support unicode in 2011 and things like "outline" in eclipse. Still the IDE is very nicely integrated with the hardware. You also got stdperiph. library from stm. It is a bit on the bloatware side, but you can mix and match the modules you like or choose to use raw registers if it makes the code more readable or smaller. Anyway, ask away, if you are interested in my experience. I also would advise against avr, becaus from the cost/performance ratio they are much worse than stm. I was porting a lot of avr code in the last month(avr's had some supply problem) and even if the avr had 16 Mhz and the stm32 had only 32, it much faster, much more configurable and has more periferials which are also easier to programm. Cortex-M3 controller are much nearer to the PC you dont have to optimize alot and 32bit wide words for calculation will spare you much pain. M3 are more comfortable to program with the things like bit banding and configurable interrupt priorities.